# Express.js and PDFKit: saving as file works, stream produces empty file

Tags: javascript, express, node-pdfkit

I am trying to create a PDF on a server with express.js and PDFKit. If I save the PDF as a file, it works as expected. However, if I try to send the content to the browser as a stream, I get a PDF, but it is empty (the 3 text blocks are missing).

```js
function createPDF(req, res) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/pdf');
      const doc = new PDFDocument;
      const stream = doc.pipe(res);
      //const stream = doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('sample.pdf'));

      // end res if pdf document finished
      stream.on('finish', () => {
        res.end();
        resolve(true);
      });

      // fill pdf
      doc.text('text');
      doc.text('text');
      doc.text('text');
     
      doc.end();
    });
  }

  app.use('/pdf-download', new PdfDownload(options, app), createPDF);
```

PdfDownload is my class which gets data for the pdf from my database. I'll later access these data by res.data.

Thanks for your help

Marc